# VBA Runtime error 1004 when trying to access range of sheet

Tags: vba, excel, range, runtime-error

I am building a small vba script that is merging tables from several workbook into one single worksheet of another workbook. The error is raised when I try to set the destination range's value:

```
wksPivotData.Range(wksPivotData.Cells(CurrentRow, 1)).Resize(tbl.ListRows.Count, tbl.ListColumns.Count).Value = _
    tbl.Range.Value
```

The error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-Defined or object-defined error"

I went through similar questions, and the general answer is what I found in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324921/vba-run-time-error-1004-when-trying-to-copy-paste-cells-in-a-separate-sheet): The selected cell belongs to another worksheet than the one desired.

While this makes complete sense, I still can't figure why my code breaks as I'm only using numerical reference (`CurrentRow` is a Long) and `Resize`, which should prevent me from doing such a mistake.

Additionally, I ran a couple quick tests in the Immediate window and it turns out that while the worksheet `wksPivotData` exists and I can access its name and a cell value, the range function simply doesn't work:

```
Debug.Print wksPivotData.Name
    PivotData

Debug.Print wksPivotData.Cells(1, 1).Value
    123
```

Both of those work but the next one doesn't:

```
Debug.Print wksPivotData.Range(1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line, `Debug.Print wksPivotData.Range(1, 1).Value` won't print because you're misuing `Range()`.  I assume you want A1?

When using `Range(1,1)`, you're referring to a non-existent range.  If you want to do cell A1, you need

```
With wksPivotData
   myData = .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(1,1)).Value
End with
```

Since you're using multiple worksheets, I'd use the `with` statement as above.  Another way to write the same thing is `wksPivotData.Range(wksPivotData.Cells(1,1),wksPivotData.Cells(1,1))` (You need to explicitly tell Excel what sheet you want to refer to when using `Range()` and `cells()`.

Finally, for your resize, if I recall correctly, you're going to have to add the same `Cell()` twice in your range:

```
wksPivotData.Range(wksPivotData.Cells(CurrentRow, 1),ksPivotData.Cells(CurrentRow, 1)).Resize(tbl.ListRows.Count, tbl.ListColumns.Count).Value = _
    tbl.Range.Value
```

Or, for the same thing, but different way of doing it:

```
With wksPivotData
    .Range(.Cells(currentRow, 1), .Cells(currentRow, 1)).Resize(tbl.ListedRows.Count, tbl.ListColumns.Count).Value = tbl.Range.Value
End With
```

Comment: Worked!! I misunderstood the arguments of Range(). Thanks!!

Comment: Pay special attention to using `wksPivotData.Range(Cells(1,1),cells(1,2))`  or something.  Note how I didn't use `wksPivotData.Cells()`.  This *could* (not necessarily will) cause issues, since you didn't specify which sheet's cells to use.  That's why I prefer using `with` often, even if it takes up two additional lines, I know the `.Cells()` will be okay...does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does. That's what I understood from other related questions.