# Run-time error '1004 , copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values from a range of cells in one sheet to
a range of cells in another sheet.Below is my code.

```
wbCandidate.Worksheets(AllBOsheetName).Range(Cells(cntCandidate, 1),    Cells(cntCandidate, 32)).Copy _

Destination:=wbCandidate.Worksheets(currentSheetName).Range(Cells(cnt, 1), Cells(cnt, 32))
```

Any idea why I am getting below error

Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: See if  this can be any help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324921/vba-run-time-error-1004-when-trying-to-copy-paste-cells-in-a-separate-sheet

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324921/vba-run-time-error-1004-when-trying-to-copy-paste-cells-in-a-separate-sheet) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link which is talking about the same issue.
 https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/210684